# sqlite insert into table select * from

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, etl

I need to move data from one table to another in my Android app

I would like  to use the following sql:

```
insert into MYTABLE2 select id, STATUS risposta, DATETIME('now') data_ins from  MYTABLE 2
```

Unfortunately in table MYTABLE2  there is an _ID column AUTOINCREMENT.
What could I do?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** 
this is my MYTABLE2 the, the table I would like to populate with data from another table:

```
CREATE TABLE "ANSWERS" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
"ID_QUESTION" INTEGER,"DATE_INS" DATETIME DEFAULT 
(CURRENT_DATE) , "ANSWER" INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

explicitly specify the column name in the `INSERT` clause,

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable (risposta, data_ins)
SELECT STATUS risposta, DATETIME('now') data_ins 
FROM   sourceTable
```

Comment: #JW 웃 If I do this it says: MYTABLE2 has x columns but y values were supplied. Where y =x+1. It seems _id primary key autoincrement is needed as well

Comment: it will generate an exception. the number of values must match with the number of columns specified.

Comment: you can pass `NULL`, this is a simplified example, `INSERT INTO destTable(DestinationID, OtherID, ColA) SELECT NULL, OtherID, COlA, FROM SourceTable`

Answer (score 6):

This might help, a query from one table to another and it will also check if the selected column (id) already exist in another table.

SQLite QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2(id,data_ins ) 
SELECT id, data_ins FROM MYTABLE2
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM MYTABLE1)
```

Android:

```
 String select_insert_query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_MYTABLE2
            + "( " + ID + "," + DATA_INS + ") SELECT "
            + ID + ","
            + DATA_INS + " FROM "
            + TABLE_MYTABLE2
            + " WHERE " + ID + " NOT IN (SELECT " + ID
            + " FROM " + TABLE_MYTABLE1 + ")";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select_insert_query, null);
    cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify which columns you're inserting into.  Assuming that the `_id` column is `autoincrement` and you're inserting the other two columns, you can have something like this:

```
insert into MYTABLE2 (riposta, data_ins)
select STATUS risposta, DATETIME('now') data_ins from  MYTABLE 2
```

Comment: #Aleks G If I do this it says: MYTABLE2 has x columns but y values were supplied. Where y =x+1

Comment: @Gyonder Are you sure you removed your `id` column from the select clause?