# SQLite Insert value and select

Tags: sqlite

I need to insert a row like following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES (1, SELECT otherName FROM table2);
```

Is it possible in SQLite?

Comment: I would suggest to be a bit more specific in your question.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the syntax you are looking for:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name)
SELECT 1, otherName
FROM table2
```

Have a look at [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838896/sqlite-insert-into-table-select-from) which covers a similar question.

Comment: @XFreeUser Happy to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm

> You can populate data into a table through select statement over
>   another table provided another table has a set of fields, which are
>   required to populate first table. Here is the syntax:

```
 INSERT INTO first_table_name [(column1, column2, ... columnN)]    
 SELECT column1, column2, ...columnN    
 FROM second_table_name   
 [WHERE condition];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
INSERT INTO test2 values(1,(Select name from test1 where id=1))
```

Here i tested it on SQLite : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9bcff/1

Answer (score -1):

AM using java , so you can use some thing like this

```
prep = Db_Connector.connection.prepareStatement("insert into reg_member values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            prep.setString(2, surname);
            prep.setString(3, lastname);         
            prep.execute();
            prep.close();
            Db_Connector.killObjects(Db_Connector.statement, Db_Connector.connection);
```