# SQLite syntax error - a comma

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to copy a row in a SQLite table, but I get a syntax error:

```
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tokens(colour, power, ts) SELECT (colour, power, ts) FROM tokens WHERE _id = 1
```

My query looks like this:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TOKENS + "(" + COLUMN_COLOUR + ", " + COLUMN_POWER + ", " + COLUMN_TS + ")" +
            " SELECT (" + COLUMN_COLOUR + ", " + COLUMN_POWER + ", " + COLUMN_TS + ")" +
            " FROM " + TABLE_TOKENS +
            " WHERE _id = " + id);
```

For me it looks fine and I guess it wouldn't work without commas...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16838896/438992

Comment: Plus you should definitely Google "SQL injection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select projection is syntactically not correct. Change `SELECT (colour, power, ts)` to `SELECT colour, power, ts`.

Comment: I went through many threads regarding copying a row and in every one of them there were these brackets. Can't believe no one pointed that out. It works now, thanks!