# SQLite How do I separate a table by column values?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm writing a simple stock trading site with Flask while learning how to use SQLite database. When a logged in user makes a transaction (buy/sell), I insert it into the `transactions` database with this command:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price) VALUES (:user_id, :symbol, :shares, :price)",
           user_id=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol, shares=shares, price=price)
```

If the user wants to check what stocks they currently have, I just query it from the database:

```
trades = db.execute("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY transaction_id ASC",
                    user_id=session["user_id"])
```

But this gives me back all of the transactions for both buy and sell. The way I set it up is that when a user sells a stock, the shares column will be a negative number. At this point it became pretty messy for me to organize the data in my code. But I'm not sure if I should add another database since I will also have to insert and query that database separately in my code.

Is there a command that allows me to split buy and sell transactions into two separate tables?

Edit: Typo in command

Comment: can't you just make 2 database calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show the buy orders you just need to filter the `select` query by fetching all rows where `shares` are positive

```
trades = db.execute("
    SELECT * FROM transactions 
    WHERE user_id = :user_id AND shares > 0 
    ORDER BY transaction_id ASC",
    user_id=session["user_id"]
)
```

However, if you want to show the total holdings for each stock/symbol, you can use a `group by` clause and sum the `shares` column.

```
holdings = db.execute("
    SELECT id, symbol, SUM(shares) 
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE user_id = :user_id
        AND SUM(shares) > 0 -- Edit: Added this so it will only show stocks you own
    GROUP BY symbol 
    ORDER BY transaction_id ASC",
    user_id=session["user_id"]
)
```

**Sidenote**: I believe that the `id` is wrong in your second `select` query and you mean `user_id` (in the `WHERE id = :user_id` part).

Comment: You're right. I was typing out my code in this question while looking at my IDE so I didn't catch that error.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I was dreading having to create another database.

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You could run two queries `insert into select ...`.
See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838896/sqlite-insert-into-table-select-from) about how to do one.

You'd just have to run a first one for the sell transactions and another one for the buy transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id = :user_id and shares > 0 ORDER BY transaction_id ASC
```

to get shares they own, and then `shares < 0` to get shares they've sold?