# sqlite upsert query syntax?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

table register

| key | app |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | insta |

table inbox

| EventSourceApplication | EventName | MessageId(primarykey) | MessageText | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| facebook | appointmentbooked | CAR20124 | SUCCESSFULL | ok |

I want to upsert into table inbox only if there is a specific data in table register in this case key = 123 & app = insta

my query is like

```
INSERT INTO inbox(EventSourceApplication,EventName,MessageId ,MessageText,status)
VALUES ('fb1','appointmentbooked','CAR201246','SUCCESSFULL','nope') ON CONFLICT(MessageId) 
DO UPDATE SET EventSourceApplication = EXCLUDED.EventSourceApplication,
EventName = EXCLUDED.EventName,MessageText=EXCLUDED.MessageText
WHERE (SELECT 1 FROM register WHERE key='123' AND app = 'insta')
```

Is the query wrong ? since i am able to insert into inbox even if wrong data is given

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlite insert into table select \* from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838896/sqlite-insert-into-table-select-from)

Comment: i am not moving data between tables i am only checking if data is present in table register then only upsert table insert where columns in both table are interdependent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause that you need is valid only in a `SELECT` statement, so instead of `VALUES` use `SELECT` and use `EXISTS` properly:

```
INSERT INTO inbox(EventSourceApplication, EventName, MessageId, MessageText, status)
SELECT 'fb1', 'appointmentbooked', 'CAR201246', 'SUCCESSFULL', 'nope' 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM register WHERE key='123' AND app = 'insta') 
ON CONFLICT(MessageId) DO UPDATE SET 
  EventSourceApplication = EXCLUDED.EventSourceApplication,
  EventName = EXCLUDED.EventName,
  MessageText=EXCLUDED.MessageText;
```

Comment: what if i want to give ? inplace of actual values for ex:- VALUES(?,?,?,?)  can i use select there?and give values later

Comment: @jeena yes, use `SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ...`